# WP-Cli wc product create Custom attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-cli

Good day,

I'm using the `wp-cli` for adding products to Wordpress, for example i use this one:

```
wp --allow-root wc product create --user=1 --name="Restricted" --regular_price=1
```

I do have some attributes called test_1 (checkbox for yes) and test_2 is a multiselect. But is there a way to fill that attributes?

I did try this:

```
wp wc product create --user=1 --name="Restricted" --regular_price=1 --test_1=yes --test_2=testvalue,testvalue2
```

But that did result in an error:

```
Error: Parameter errors:
 unknown --test_1 parameter
 unknown --test_2 parameter
```

And did this one, but the values were still empty:

```
 wp wc product create --user=1 --name="Restricted" --regular_price=1 --attributes='[{"test_1": "yes", "test_2": ["testvalue","testvalue2"]}]'
```

And this one:

```
wp wc product create --user=1 --name="Restricted" --regular_price=1 --attributes='[{"test_1": 1, "test_2": ["testvalue","testvalue2"]]'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `attributes` as JSON. Since you have 2 attributes, the proper command along with JSON Structure is.

```
wp wc product create --name='Product Name'  --user=1 
    --attributes='[ 
        { "name": "test_1", "visible": true, "options" : ["yes", "no"] }, 
        { "name": "test_2", "visible": true, "options" : ["small", "medium"] } 
    ]'
```

Check the 2nd FAQ [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/WC-CLI-Overview#frequently-asked-questions)

It says that certain properties needs to be passed as JSON.

> Some 'lists' are objects, for example, if you want to set categories for a product the REST API expects an array of objects: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties

Answer (score 1):

this reference to create woocommerce product using WP-CLI

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/WC-CLI-Overview#frequently-asked-questions

https://nicola.blog/2016/03/10/managing-products-woocommerce-cli/

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties

```
if you add product Custom attributes or category through CLI than use  JSON format like this

 --attributes= [{ "name": "color", "visible": true, "options":["black","blue"]}]
 --categories= [ { "id" : category_id } ]

Example demo:-

wp wc product create --name="mobile11" --description="this is mobile 11" --type=simple --regular_price=500 --sale_price=400 --user=dharmesh --categories='[ { "id" : 35 } ]' --attributes='[{ "name": "color", "visible": true, "options":["black","blue","red"]}]' --allow-root
```

Comment: How can I add a new attribute? called `custom_color` to each product `where color = 'black'` with `WP CLi`

Comment: This nailed it for me. +1 for the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time terminal isn't formatted properly sometimes it skips , sometime not formatting bash variable causes empty values. It depends how you're using declaring bash variable and using within woocommerce cli.

I was looking way correct format for adding / updating product attributes. This is how I was able to add product attributes for my product.

```
wp wc product update 2898  --user=1  --attributes='[{ "name":"Background Style","options":"White"},{ "name":"Demographic Level","options":"college-university"}]'
```

Where,

product_id is 2898
attributes are "Background Style" and "Demographic Level" and `options` are its corresponding terms.